# Laptop is connected o the internet but I can not browse with any browser

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking

My Xp Pro Sp3 laptop stopped the other day, it won't open any pages on the internet using IE8, Firefox or chrome. I can ping 8.8.8.8 and get a good response but I cant ping www.google.com I can't download any email with outlook express. I have run anti-malware bytes,  spybot S&D, tdsKiller and Sophos, all of which found stuff and cleaned it up. I can add the logs if needed. The strange thing is kaspersky Internet security is still updating albiet slowly, and Utorrent can still upload & download. The other computers on my home network are working fine.

I am really struggling to find a solution to thsi problem and hope you guys can help???

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, can you open webpages from their IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IP configuration to me.  I'd suggest checking the IP configuration of your other computers on the network and then hardcoding yourself on in the network adaptor, ipv4 settings.

Comment: the ip config is the same on both non working lapto and working desktop, bar 2 digits to the ip address. They are both plugged into the same router using a wired connection. If you have any test i can try I will be willing to try almost anything at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been infected by some exploit (which can't be ruled out at this point) then the likely thing is that your DNS settings are incorrect.  You don't provide enough detail to give specific instructions, but the DNS settings are in the network adapter properties, under the "Internet Protocol" (IPv4) properties.  I suggest this because you say you can ping an IP address but not a name, and I suspect you are putting names into your browsers.  For example, can you ping 74.125.227.169?

If your address is automatically assigned, as well as the DNS server info (which is common) then use the command "IPCONFIG /ALL" to see what the DNS servers are set to.  Compare this with another computer in the house;  if the server addresses are different, change yours to manually configure to the same as the others.

Also your response to another answer suggests that you might be using a wireless connection;  if that's the case, please specify, as that can point to a very different answer.

Comment: The DNS servers are set the same on both machines "192.168.1.1" they are assigned automatically I found them under "Internet Protocol TCP/IP " Properties as I am using XP.I can ping the address you sent and it came back 4 times with "Reply from 74.125.227.169: bytes=32 time=132ms TTL=48

Comment: Laptop is now working great, My solution after much research was to do the following in order.

I ran ADWCleaner by Xplode and scanned & cleaned it, followed by TDSSKiller and changed the parameter to inculded modules and once rebooted changed parameters to tick all boxes. This scan was clean.

I then ran RougeKiller and scanned and then clicked delete and waited until it said finish and then clicked report.

This seems to have fixed all my problems and the laptop is running great again. I found my solution by reading several posts from Bleeping Computer Forum

Comment: Glad you got it cleaned up;  I don't like to presume an exploit, but it seemed a possibility. Whatever you had was redirecting DNS queries, I'd bet -- that is, when you'd type in the name of a site, it would try to make your system go somewhere else, but your system still could get to actual IP addresses.  The programs you mention are very good tools, in the right circumstances, that just have to be used carefully. FWIW, the address I had you ping was google.com, by address instead of name.